# Pandas create a new Dataframe that stores the row count

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a new Dataframe that stores the row count of an existing Dataframe.

```
size = df.shape[0]
```

I am trying to create a new Dataframe such as `new_df = pd.Dataframe(size)` but get an error `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass values to one element list:

```
size = 2

ew_df = pd.DataFrame([size])
print (ew_df)
   0
0  2
```

Or:

```
ew_df = pd.DataFrame({'size': [size]})
#alternative
#ew_df = pd.DataFrame({'size': size}, index=[0])
print (ew_df)
   size
0     2
```

Another idea is create `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(size)
print (s)
0    2
dtype: int64
```